A sum/integral related to amount of products of 2 distinct primes
The overall product I'm working on, is showing that
$$\pi_2(x)=x\frac{\log\log x}{\log x}+O(\frac{x}{\log x}),$$
using the PNT, where $\pi_2(x)$ denotes the amount of numbers less than $x$, which are the product of 2 distinct primes. The part I'm stuck on, is showing that
$$\sum_{p\leq\sqrt{x}}\frac{x}{p\log(\frac{x}{p})}=x\int_2^\sqrt{x}\frac{1}{t\log(\frac{x}{t})\log(t)}dt+O(\frac{x}{\log x}),$$
using summation by parts, and that
$$x\int_2^\sqrt{x}\frac{1}{t\log(\frac{x}{t})\log(t)}dt=x\frac{\log\log x}{\log x}+O(\frac{x}{\log x})$$
My main idea so far, has been to note that $\sum_{p\leq\sqrt{x}}\frac{x}{p\log(\frac{x}{p})}=x\sum_{k=2}^\sqrt{x}\frac{\pi(k)-\pi(k-1)}{k\log(\frac{x}{k})}$ and then use summation by parts, and then try to apply the PNT in a clever way, but nothing has quite worked out so far.
Thanks in advance!

Your sum is related to OEIS Entry A072613 which gives a reference which might be useful.

The problem is both showing that the sum over the primes less than $\sqrt{x}$ is equal to the last integral + $O(\frac{x}{\log x})$, as well the computation of the last integral

doesn't it follow from writing $1/\log (x/p)=1/\log x+\mathcal O(p/x)$?

For the last integral $$I=\int\frac{dt}{t\,\log(\frac{x}{t})\,\log(t)}$$
$$t=e^u \quad \implies \quad I=\int \frac{du}{u \log (x)-u^2}$$ Partial fraction decomposition
$$I=\frac{1}{\log (x)}\Bigg(\int \frac{du}{u }-\int \frac{du}{u-\log (x)}\Bigg)=\frac{1}{\log (x)}\,\log \left(\frac{u}{u-\log (x)}\right)$$ Back to $t$ and the bounds, assuming $x >4$
$$J=x\int_2^\sqrt{x}\frac{dt}{t\log(\frac{x}{t})\log(t)}=\frac{x}{\log (x)}\,\log \left(\frac{\log (x)}{\log (2)}-1\right)$$ For large $x$ $$J\sim \frac{x}{\log (x)}\,\log \left(\frac{\log (x)}{\log (2)}\right) \sim \frac{x \log (\log (x))}{\log (x)}$$
Edit
$$x=2^y \qquad \implies \qquad J=\frac{2^y\, \log (y-1)}{y\, \log (2)}$$ Expanded as series for large $y$
$$J=\frac {2^y}{y\,\log(2)} \Bigg(\log (y)-\frac{1}{y}-\frac{1}{2 y^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{y^3}\right)\Bigg)$$
